# Cloud Identity Platform: Are IdP-initiated SAML flows possible?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

Google Cloud Identity Platform has [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-enable-application-for-saml) for Service Provider-initiated SAML auth flows. After searching the docs and online, I can't find anything about Identity Provider-initiated flows.

Are IdP-initiated SAML flows supported at all by Identity Platform? Assuming I'm using the firebase JS SDK, what would receiving the IdP SamlResponse POST even look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I just found that the [current docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-enable-application-for-saml) call out:

> Currently, only service-provider (SP) initiated SAML flows via the web SDK are supported.

Answer (score 1):

We can create our own ACS handler endpoint

```
  route.post('/sso/callback', (samlResponse) => {
   // 1. Use passport saml or saml2 to parse the saml response
   // 2. Then create a claim
    const userId = samlResponse.user.uid;
    const additionalClaims = {
      premiumAccount: true,
      userGroups: []
    };
    
    admin
      .auth()
      .createCustomToken(userId, additionalClaims)
      .then((customToken) => {
        // Send token back to client
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
      });
    });
```

and then in the client application

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
```