# Cloud Identity Platform make Custom SAML ACS Callback

Tags: google-cloud-functions, saml, saml-2.0, google-cloud-identity

I'm trying to make a custom SAML app to integrate with Google Workspace (i.e. so that if a person in the organization wants to access it, they could do so from the apps list on google.com).

Because Google Cloud Identity Platform only supports service provider-initiated login, this does not seem possible using the default callback URL they provide. I saw [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66916213/9947487), and was hoping to implement something like this. However, the SAMLResponse coming in seems to be encrypted, and I don't know enough about the encryption process to know how to decrypt it (or if that's even possible).

I'm using a Cloud Function as my callback URL, and to be clear I'm trying to decrypt the `res.body.SAMLResponse` string:

```
exports.samlACSCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.SAMLResponse)
})
```

My best guess is that it's somehow related to the certificate that I had to copy from the Google Admin console to the Cloud Identity setup page?